# How to avoid !! in a function which returns a non-nullable

Tags: kotlin, nullable

In the sample below,  the function should return a non-null data.
Since the data could be changed in the process, it needs to be var, and can only be nullable to start with.

I can't use `lateinit` because the first call of `if (d == null)` will throw.

After the process it will be assigned a non-null data, but the return has to use the `!!` (double bang or non-null assertion operator).

What is the best approach to avoid the `!!`?

```
fun testGetLowest (dataArray: List<Data>) : Data {
   var d: Data? = null
   for (i in dataArray.indecs) {

       if (d == null) {// first run
           d = dataArray[i]
       } else if {
           d.level < dataArray[i].level
           d = dataArray[i]
       }
    }
    return d!!
}
```

Comment: What if the provided list is empty?

Comment: This entire function can be replaced with `return dataArray.minBy { it.level }`. You still need to take care of the empty list case.

Comment: this sample is for showing the '!!' issue, assuming dataArray is not empty.

Comment: The type system isn't assuming anything, you are. So no, `!!` is the way to go

Comment: @yole, thx! the sample may be replaced with `dataArray.minBy { it.level }`,  but it is trying to show in some case it has to use `var d: Data?` then it will force to use '!!' later.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't like `!!` then supply a default value for it. You'll realize you can only supply the default value if the list is not empty, but, as you said, the list is already known to be non-empty. The good part of this story is that the type system doesn't track list size so when you say `dataArray[0]`, it will take your word for it.

```
fun testGetLowest(dataArray: List<Data>) : Data {
    var d: Data = dataArray[0]
    for (i in 1 until dataArray.size) {
        if (d.level < dataArray[i].level) {
            d = dataArray[i]
        }
    }
    return d
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Even if you were to convert it to an `Option`, you would still have to deal with the case when `dataArray` is empty and so the value returned is undefined.

If you wanted to make this a complete function instead of throwing an exception, you can return an `Option<Data>` instead of a `Data` so that the case of an empty `dataArray` would return a `None` and leave it up to the caller to deal with how to handle the sad path.

Answer (score 1):

Normally, you can and should lean on the compiler to infer nullability. This is not always possible, and in the contrived example if the inner loop runs but once `d` is non-null. This is guaranteed to happen if `dataArray` has at least one member.

Using this knowledge you could refactor the code slightly using [require](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin/require.html) to check the arguments (for at least one member of the array) and [checkNotNull](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin/check-not-null.html) to assert the state of the `dataArray` as a post-condition.

```
fun testGetLowest (dataArray: List<Data>) : Data {
   require(dataArray.size > 0, { "Expected dataArray to have size of at least 1: $dataArray")
   var d: Data? = null
   for (i in dataArray.indecs) {

       if (d == null) {// first run
           d = dataArray[i]
       } else if {
           d.level < dataArray[i].level
           d = dataArray[i]
       }
    }
    return checkNotNull(d, { "Expected d to be non-null through dataArray having at least one element and d being assigned in first iteration of loop" })
}
```

Remember you can return the result of a `checkNotNull` (and similar operators):

```
val checkedD = checkNotNull(d)
```

See Google Guava's [Preconditions](https://github.com/google/guava/wiki/PreconditionsExplained) for something similar.

Answer (score 0):

## How to do the same check, and cover the empty case

```
fun testGetLowest(dataArray: List<Data>) 
    = dataArray.minBy { it.level } ?: throw AssertionError("List was empty")
```

This uses the `?:` operator to either get the minimum, or if the minimum is null (the list is empty) throws an error instead.

Answer (score 0):

The accepted answer is completly fine but just to mentioned another way to solve your problem by changing one line in your code: `return d ?: dataArray[0]`